# Type for string with undetermined ending

Tags: typescript, types

I have a string, it starts with some prefix. How can i define a type which correspond to something like this:

```
 type group_of_strings = 'custom_name ' + string
```

Where string is a type. So purpose of this to filter all strings which are not belong to group of strings starting with this particular prefix. Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: maybe you can use String Enums, to be included in the next version of TypeScript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15486 . You can test them now using typescript@next

Comment: thank you for suggestion i will check this out

Comment: how would you use string enums to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible? Thank you.

No. It cannot be specified at compile time using TypeScript / FlowType / Google Clojure / Dart type systems.

Other tools might but I am familiar enough with these to give an exact answer

## Alternative

You can model it as

```
type group_of_strings = 
 {
   prefix: 'custom_name ',
   suffix: string
 }
```

But it wouldn't be a string literal in this case and instead be an object containing two string properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done using [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html):

```
type PrefixedString = `custom_name${string}`;
```